# Is there a way to convert an object array to an array of certain property, in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

My Tag Scheme:

```
{  
_id:xxxx,  
name:String,  
}
```

Let's say I have two documents:

```
{_id:xxxx,  name:a}  
{_id:xxxx,  name:b}
```

I want to get all tag names and return as an array: [a,b].
Is there a simple way to do it? I'm using mongoose.

Comment: Yes, use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: `[{_id:'xxxx',  name:'a'},{_id:'xxxx',  name:'b'}].map(function(obj){return obj.name});` -> `['a','b']` per cookie monster's comment:.

Comment: Or soon... `array.map(obj => obj.name)` ... I wonder if it can be done right now in NodeJS with the harmony flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all instances, after building Tag model, use the find() method on your model:

```
    Tag.find({}, function(err, tags) {
         if(!err){
        console.log(tags);
      }

});
```